# High-resolution symbol markers in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, retina-display

I'm wondering how I can get the Google Maps JavaScript API to display the integrated *SymbolPath* icons as high-resolution (Retina) images. Right now, they look horrible on Smartphone-Screens (tested on an iPhone).

That's how I define the icon:

```
icon: {
  path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
  scale: 10
}
```

as described in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-symbol-predefined). The low resolution of the icon can be seen on this page.

A possible solution would be to provide a circle as a (high resolution) PNG file, but I'd rather avoid such dirty hacks for simple tasks like drawing a circle.

Comment: I don't know what you see on your iPhone but it looks fine on mine. These predefined symbols are vector SVG symbols. It's just a SVG path and therefore there is no high/low resolution. You can also create your own symbols using the [SVG path notation](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathData). See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/symbols

Comment: I'm aware of what an SVG path is, but nevertheless they are not rendered correctly. The same problem occurs when using the SVG path notation. See http://imgur.com/96fSokB for a screenshot of the documentation.

Comment: As far as I found out, this is a known issue in the Google Maps API: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6358

Comment: I'm having the same issue, didn't notice until someone looked on a Retina. I think it's because the CIRCLE is rendered as an image. I found that SVGs saved from Illustrator look great though. The properties for the Marker are handled a little different. Here are a couple of files I made to compare. The difference is really only visible on a high res montior. [SVG](http://workalicio.us/google-maps/marker-symbol-icon-svg.html) vs [CIRCLE PATH](http://workalicio.us/google-maps/marker-symbol-icon-path.html)